Verify username and password and get session timeout via Rest API
I need to verify username/password and get session timeout via Rest API. How to do that? I found this solution on https://github.com/kabbo06/radius_auth_using_api. The solution is ok to verify username/password only. It does not provide solution to get session timeout for the username.
I need example of configuration and Rest API (request and respond).
